# Why `Outer.Inner inner = o.new Inner();` not `Outer.Inner inner = o.new Outer.Inner();`?

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
class Outer {    
    class Inner {       

    }    
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Outer o = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner inner = o.new Inner();    

    }    
}
```

Why is

```
Outer.Inner inner = o.new Inner();
```

not

```
Outer.Inner inner = o.new Outer.Inner();
```

i.e. why qualifying type declaration of `inner` with outer class name, but not qualifying the inner class' constructor with the outer class name?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to `o.` compiler already knows of which type you want to create nested instance so it lets us omit it in `o.new ...` part.

Comment: Can it be not omitted?

Comment: @Ben I am not sure what you mean by "Can it be not omitted"? Do you want to prevent compiler from allowing omitting it? Why?

Comment: @Pshemo I think it's just an awkward double negative: "can it be included?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JLS 15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), you are talking about a *qualified class instance creation expression*:

> *Qualified class instance creation expressions* begin with a `Primary` expression or an `ExpressionName`

(Yours starts with a primary expression)

The syntax is given as:

> ```
> ClassInstanceCreationExpression:
>   UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression
>   ExpressionName . UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression
>   Primary . UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression
>
> UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression:
>   new [TypeArguments] ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate ( [ArgumentList] ) [ClassBody]
>
> ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate:
>   {Annotation} Identifier {. {Annotation} Identifier} [TypeArgumentsOrDiamond]
>
> TypeArgumentsOrDiamond:
>   TypeArguments 
>   <>
> ```

A bit lower down, in 15.9.1, it says:

> The `Identifier` in `ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate` must unambiguously denote an inner class that is accessible, non-final, not an enum type, and a member of the compile-time type of the `Primary` expression or the `ExpressionName`. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

So, it has to be a member of the type of the expression. As such, there is no need to qualify it, as it cannot be anything *but* a class inside `Outer`.

It would simply be redundant to have to specify the `Outer.`.

Answer (score 4):

Because `o` is already an instance of type `Outer`, you don't need to create another `Outer` instance to create the `Inner` instance. The second option you list implies you are creating an instance of another inner class named `Outer` within the top-level `Outer`, which there isn't, and it will give an error. (Edit: just noticed there aren't parentheses after `o.new Outer`, which now leads me to think that you probably had the reasoning of my second paragraph).

If you mean that `Outer.Inner()` should be the constructor rather than just `Inner()`, it's because `Outer.Inner()` implies `Inner` is a static inner class. `static` was never specified, so you require an `Outer` instance.

Comment: I am not sure from where "*you don't need to create another Outer instance to create the Inner instance*" come from. `o.new Outer.Inner()` doesn't create *another* `Outer` instance, `Outer.Inner` is used simply as type name of *one* class - the inner one.

Comment: No, you're right. I misread the line initially and thought it said `o.new Outer().Inner()`, but there aren't parentheses.

Comment: That `o.new Outer().Inner()` wouldn't compile, it would need to be `o.new Outer().new Inner()`.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. Also, your example doesn't compile either.

Comment: @AndyTurner My bad, I meant it without `o.` like `new Outer().new Inner()`. Nice catch.

Answer (score -1):

For comparison:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void foo(){
       System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

We can **foo** in two ways:

1)

```
Demo.foo();  // with Demo qualifier
```

2)

```
Demo d = new Demo();
d.foo();  // without Demo qualifier!
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The `Inner` class OP referenced is an instance class, not static as is your `foo` method, so the comparison isn't exactly correct.

Comment: "For comparison" there is no meaningful comparison to be drawn here. The language rules around methods is quite separate from the rules around class instance creation.